# Will automatic ML platforms replace the applied statistician?

Tags: modeling, careers

In the last years, we have seen rapid advances in several fields related to computing and statistics. This led to statistical/ML models that are easy to use, applicable in several tasks, and perform acceptably to some standards.

Being easy to use does not translate into correct application/interpretation of statistics. However, perhaps many industries do not really care about interpretation or correctness of the statistical methodology, they care about predictive power.

Combining this mindset with the technological advances, automatic machine learning platforms have risen. These platforms fit a bulk of models, apply data science methodology, and provide the best models to the user. It also has other interesting aspects, e.g. it leads to an easier automation of the entire process.

So it prompts us to ask: how does the man model of the applied statistician compare against the best model of these platforms for most common applications?

Some people will immediately reply: Go to competitions and see for yourself: man made models win. However, competition problems are, somehow, special problems. If they were regular problems, they probably would not be in the competitions.

Hence, the ultimate question is: what will become of the applied statistician? Will these platforms replace him? Will we employ him only in scientific/special problems in which the automation fails? Or maybe he becomes an “enhancer”: get the best model from the platforms, tweak it a bit, make sanity checks, deploy, and then rinse and repeat?

I imagine that this type of “will I lose my job to a machine?” question is quite common in this century. I wonder, however, how we statisticians fare against the machine.

Comment: In my opinion, there's no replacing people, ever. What machines are still not capable of is higher-level judgment calls. For example, what if an experiment is poorly run (too-small sample size, or using hypothesis-inducing data to test the hypothesis, or lack of controls, etc.)? How could a computer detect that? Can a computer detect conflict-of-interest? Can computers fix the reproducibility crisis? For these reasons, I say that statisticians have never been more important than now, when such abuse is made of the scientific method.

Comment: @AdrianKeister interesting points. At first glance, I agree: the machine will not beat us at every scenario. However, do most common data analysis jobs nowadays require such specialized judgment calls?

Comment: Every data analysis requires a knowledge of the data production process, a knowledge of what the columns (variables) mean, judgment as to appropriate and inappropriate techniques in given situations, and the ability to interpret results for non-technical people. All of those are higher-order skills that computers don't have.

Comment: "Or maybe he becomes an “enhancer”: get the best model from the platforms, tweak it a bit, make sanity checks, deploy, and then rinse and repeat?" -- No, I see the human statistician as the one who sets up the problem. What business or scientific problem are we even trying to solve? What response variables, what predictors, and what model-performance metric will be useful? How many samples to collect and how? How to account for data structure when we make a holdout set? Doing all this right is IMHO the hardest part... & much more important than the automatable predictive-modeling step itself.

Answer (score 3):

Will some of the things that applied statisticians do today be replaced? Almost certainly. Will applied statisticians themselves be replaced? Not quite. The thoughtfulness in your question around the role of the statistician becoming more of an "enhancer" is a great hunch. I would add to it that as it becomes easier to answer complex statistical questions, the questions that we choose to focus on become more important... which is another future shift in the role of statisticians in many applied settings.

There are two graphs that I always come back to with questions like this. The first is "The Spreadsheet Apocalypse Revisited" from [this WSJ article in 2017](https://www.wsj.com/articles/wesurvived-spreadsheets-and-well-survive-ai-1501688765). The second is a breakdown of routine and nonroutine job growth from [WSJ / The Third Way in 2015](https://www.wsj.com/articles/BL-REB-31788).

If you look at how the introduction of spreadsheet software led to a decline in bookkeeping jobs but rise in accountants / analysts, it's not much of stretch to imagine the situation you've described as a parallel. That is, as the jobs of applied statisticians get easier or automated away, statisticians are able to take on higher order functions.

Now that said, I think your intuition around which statistical / ML fields this is likely to happen in first is absolutely spot on. If all we care about is predictive power and we can treat the models as a "black box", then applying automated ML models could become a routine cognitive task (generalizing a bit, obviously). The jobs that require more non-routine cognitive tasks (application, interpretation, inference, etc.) will likely continue to have a human component for much longer.

[image: Chart1]

[image: chart 2]